# How can I tell if an e-mail address is hosted by google apps

Tags: authentication, dns, oauth-2.0

I'd like to use Google's Oauth2 API to login to an application based on an e-mail address. Considering users may not know if their me@mydomain.com is hosted by google, how could I inspect their e-mail address and redirect them to Google Auth via code? For example, on a typical login page you've seen the "login with my google account" button, but if the users doesn't know it's a google account I'd still like to use OAUTH even if they didn't click it.

I've considered a DNS lookup on the MX record, but not sure if that's the cleanest/best approach.

i.e. a typical DNS lookup returns:

```
mydomain.com      MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = aspmx.l.google.com
mydomain.com      MX preference = 20, mail exchanger = alt1.aspmx.l.google.com
mydomain.com      MX preference = 20, mail exchanger = alt2.aspmx.l.google.com
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An nslookup on MX records would probably be the most practical solution and would be rather simple.

The issue I have with this is that unless your application exclusively requires you to use their Google e-mail, you might be excluding some people.  I have an alternate e-mail address set up with my Google account and can use that to log in.  Now, I would venture to guess most users would use their Google e-mail account, but you need to be ready for the other case.

My suggestion is to first use an easier, deprecated method, like ClientLogin.  You can do a simple post using https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?Email=who@where.com&Passwd=password

If you get "Error=BadAuthentication", then the authentication failed.  If you get a good authentication, you know this e-mail address is associated with a Google account and then you can use Oauth2 to log them in.  The only issue I see with this is if the user enters an incorrect password.  I would do some research across all of the Google APIs to see if any of them can tell you about an incorrect password vs. just a failed login, though that might not exist for security purposes.

Anyway, good luck.  Keep us updated if you come up with something else.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My thought was that the user would ONLY enter their e-mail address. Upon clicking "login", the server would determine how to authenticate the user. If it's a google [apps] account then use Google OAUTH2, if it's Yahoo, use their oauth services, if it's neither then have the user create a password just for my site.

Comment: The MX record then would be your best best, but there is no sure way to make sure you include everyone in that case.  Wouldn't it just be easier to have them click on a button so they log in using that account if they choose to?  That's how most sites handle this.